# Is this a poorly worded probability question? Unsolvable?

Tags: probability

The question says: ***"For a recent year, 0.99 of the incarcerated population is adults and 0.07 is female. If an incarcerated person is picked at random, find the probability that the person is female given they are an adult."***

I've been thinking about this for more than 4 hours and it just doesn't seem solvable to me.

We need the intersection(percentage of those that are females and adults) to use the following formula, but there is no way to find that.

${\mathbb{P(}F|A)= \mathbb{P}(F\cap A)}/{\mathbb{P}(A)}$

---

I tried to solve a similar but simpler problem that I made up such as:

***In a population of 10 people, 8 of them(80%) are adults, and 4 of the total population are females(40%); what is the percentage of female adults?***

I tried to visualize it as a set: $\{1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20\}$ and ask **if 80% of the set elements are positive and 40% of the set elements are divisible by 3, what is the percentage of positive numbers that are divisible by 3 in the set?**

Is the original question really flawed? Or did my brain stop working because I can't think clearly anymore since I saw that question.

Comment: Hint: the probability of the person being both a female and an adult is $(0.99)(0.07)$. You will then be able to use conditional probability formulas to determine your answer.

Comment: Can you please explain why that is true? If only 1 of the females is adult and the rest are minors, or all are adults except for 1, how does (0.99*0.07) account for that?

Comment: While not explicitly stated in the question, the assumption one makes is that the probabilities are independent. We can therefore use $P(A\cap{b})=P(A)P(B)$

Comment: Yes, the problem is underspecified. It is consistent that all of the incarcerated females are adults, as well as that all of the incarcerated minors are female. So anything between $\frac{6}{99}$ and $\frac{7}{99}$ is possible.

Comment: @user130512 "the assumption one makes is that the probabilities are independent" Do we make this assumption? Do we wish to make it? Does it make sense to make it?

Comment: @Did Question is poorly stated. I am just providing him with the way that the person who posed the question would likely want it to be solved

Comment: @user130512 Yes I know this is what you are doing, and I object to it. The FIRST piece of information to provide is that the question does not make sense as stated.

Comment: @Did I definitely would not state the question like that. But I doubt his teacher/professor is looking for a theoretical range of answers to his word problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the assumption of *independence* the answer is obviously $0.07$. 
That assumption is not necessarily reasonable. So indeed the question is poorly worded.

Imagine as an extreme case that no child females are put in jail. Then the probability a jailed person is female given the person is an adult is  $\frac{0.07}{0.99}$.

As an opposite extreme case, suppose that no male children are put in jail. Then  the probability is $\frac{0.06}{0.99}$. This is because the females account for all the child prisoners, leaving the proportion $0.06$ of the total that are both adult and female.